# Open Image from solution folder vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, path

i need open image from solution folder (the name of the folder is Images)
that image is always copied to that directory, i tried this:

```
Dim src As String = "../Images/Logos/" & ImageName
Dim MyImage As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(src)
```

But no works, only works if i put all the directory path like: C:/.../ImageName.jpg

Comment: thats because `"../Images/Logos/" & ImageName` will result in something like `"../Images/Logos/foobar.jpg"` which is not a valid path.  Depending on what you are doing with these, you'd be better off loading from a folder in Users (AppData) - "solution folders" may or may not exist at runtime since they are a VS concoction to organize your project files.

Answer (score 1):

Go up two directories... (solution folder\bin\release)

```
Dim src As String = "..\..\Images\Logos\" & ImageName
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer;

```
Dim src As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "Images\Logos\" & ImageName
```